# Magento 2.1.3 EE special price not showing

Tags: magento2

I am having big problems with special price after updating from 2.0.7 to Magento 2.1.3 Enterprise.

Steps:

1. install a Magento 2.1.3 EE vanilla with sample data
2. create a product with regular price
3. edit that product and add a special price

Expected:

- you should see the special price being shown on the frontend

Actual:

- you can't see the special price.

I am suspecting the Staging modules are not working properly.
Do you know any known issues with this ?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Please do indexing and flush cache.

> command to reset index: php bin/magento indexer:reset
>
> command to  reindex: php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> command to flush cache: php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> command to clean cache: php bin/magento cache:clean